# node.js - portable across two machines?

Tags: node.js

I have a complex node/express app that **runs fine locally and on server**.  When we clone the project on another laptop, we are getting the http.js header error:

```
http.js:689
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

I've been through all the answers here and been through the code line by line - the only thing I've found is that calls to the 'req' object in node seem to cause the error to happen:

```
console.log(req.params.docId); //(causes error - docId is undefined in this case)
```

for route:

```
app.get('/:user/:docId', homeController.index);
```

Again, **the code runs fine on one laptop and one server but not on 2nd laptop**.  Is this a dependency issue?  We've tried manually copying all node_modules.  How can we fix this?

node v0.10.28, running with nodemon v1.2.1

Comment: have tried matching nodemon versions (v1.0.19) since this seems to affect http module, but no change.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this resource: https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/751. A search here on SO will bring some versions of this question that might serve you too.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @reydellon it looks like we had a loose next() in our code and for whatever reason it never errored on us before.

I guess this error is always a code issue.. check out the resource posted above for more

Comment: Double callbacks are sometimes very difficult to track down in node, especially when it occurs infrequently